# Calculating error values in an MA(2) process

Tags: time-series, moving-average

I have a numerical MA process that I am struggling with.

I have been given a $t = 119$ time series and must forecast the next 5 terms using a MA(2) model as shown

$$_ = 2 + _ + 0.5_{−1} - 0.1_{−2}$$

I know to forecast the next term I can use this equation

$$E(_|_{−1}) = 2 + 0.5_{−1} - 0.1_{−2}$$

I have the formula for the errors $_ = _ − E(_|_{−1})$  where $_{−1}$ is all of the information up to that point. So if I want to calculate $_{−1}$ for example must I then recursively calculate the errors for all previous elements?

Or if my last element is say $65$, can I say

$$_{−1} = _{-1} − E(_{-1}|_{−2}) = 65 - 2 = 63$$

Seeing as the expectation of my process is 2.

Sorry if this all over the place Ive been working on it for 2 hours to no avail.

Comment: You cannot calculate the errors that will be experienced in the future: you can only estimate how large they might be and incorporate that in a *prediction interval* for your forecast.  It sounds like you are working on a homework exercise, in which case consulting your text or notes for formulas and concepts might be the most productive thing you can do at this point.

Comment: but for calculating previous errors, say i have 119 elements and my last one is 65. I want to forecast the 120th, can i say (−1) = 65 - 2 = 63? thank you for the reply!

Comment: I don't see how that equation follows from your model, which says $\varepsilon_{t-1} = Y_{t-1} - 2 - 0.5\varepsilon_{t-2} - 0.1\varepsilon_{t-3}.$ You can't ignore those last two terms.